# Getting 404 error in Struts2 application

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am first time doing my simple application with Struts2.

Here is my code,

ActionExample :

```
package com.demo;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;


public class ActionExample implements Action
{

    @Override
    public String execute()  {

        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

success.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

Success Page!.........

</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" 
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<action name="run" class="com.demo.ActionExample">
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StrutsFirstApplication</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>success.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
  <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class> 
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I am doing by this video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATrmHSfh6Tc

Even i am getting 404 error when run this url :8080/StrutsFirstApplication/run.action

why and how to fix this?

Comment: have you configure welcome file? what version of struts2 you are using ?

Comment: change filter class to <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

Comment: why should i change? In that video they didnt change the <filter-class>!

Comment: what version you are using for struts2 it depends on that. as your filter is deprecated for newer version.

Comment: I dont understand.I am doing exactly what that video telling know. please make me clear Mr.

Comment: actually it may possible that video was made when struts2 version 2.1.3 were used but now above mention filter use and apache recommend that you have to use new filter instead of older one.

Comment: when copy and past that filter class my file got error as An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
1.why?its not opening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67535/discussion-between-manoj-sharma-and-manivasagam).

Comment: possible duplicate of [why getting error as Failed to start component \[StandardEngine\[Catalina\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618908/why-getting-error-as-failed-to-start-component-standardenginecatalina)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't posted your index.jsp. It should be something like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
...
...
<form action="run">
<s:submit/>
</form>
```

And your struts.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<action name="run" class="default.ActionExapmle " method="execute">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>

  </package>
</struts>
```

Now, i don't know if it's correct to use all that welcome-file in your web.xml file, try using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your configuration file check below and match:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <action-mappings>
        <<action name="run" class="com.demo.ActionExample">
            <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp"/>
        </action>

    </action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

change accordingly. i recommend that you should switch to struts2 as struts1 is EOL.

Comment: It shows error like "content of element must consist of well-formed character data or markup".why?

Answer (score -1):

It has been a while i have worked on struts but  i think the return of the action should match the string in xml configuraion

I mean

```
public String execute()  {

        return SUCCESS; // returns SUCCESS and not success
    }
```

and your xml has

```
<action name="run" class="com.demo.ActionExample">
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Make the return string same on both ends, i hope that might work.

Comment: @rastogi have you checked what is SUCCESS. it static final variable which hold success as string literal.